# How can I refactor this EF Core query to add another where condition variable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have this query below that looks for a transfer with a user id in either the SenderId or ReceiverId column.

```
// transferParams.Transfer = null,1,2 
var transfersCount = await _dbContext.Transfers
   .Where(p => 
     (p.SenderId == userFromRepo.Id || p.ReceiverId == userFromRepo.Id) &&
     (!transferParams.Status.HasValue || p.TransferStatus == (TransferStatus)transferParams.Status) &&
     (!transferParams.Type.HasValue || p.TransferType == (TransferType)transferParams.Type))
.CountAsync();
```

I've now passed in another parameter in the controller called 'Transfer' that's a nullable Int where 1 is Received and 2 is Sent.

I need to refactor the query so that if the transfer parameter that's passed in is null I will still look in both columns (ReceiverId, SenderId), but if it's 1 then I'll only look in the ReceiverId column and if 2 only look in the SenderId column.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var baseQuery = _dbContext.Transfers.AsQueryable();
switch(transfer)
{
  case 1:
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(p => p.ReceiverId == user.Id);
    break;
  case 2:
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(p => p.SenderId == user.Id);
    break;
  default:
    baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(p => p.ReceiverId == user.Id || p.SenderId == user.Id);
    break;
}
if (transferParams.Status.HasValue)
  baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(p=> p.TransferStatus == (TransferStatus)transferParams.Status);
if (transferParams.Type.HasValue)
  baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(p => p.TransferType == (TransferType)transferParams.Type);
var transferCount = await baseQuery.CountAsync();
```

Comment: This is what I would suggest too. It *could* be done all in one line, but it would be confusing. Using `switch` is far more readable.

Comment: Is a case statement the only way to do it? Isn't there some 1 line way?

Comment: Let me post the whole query as I only posted part.

Comment: Yes, the alternative is something like .Where(p => (transfer == 1 && p.ReceiverId == user.Id) || (transfer == 2 && p.SenderId == user.Id) || (transfer is null && (p.ReceiverId == user.Id || p.SenderId == user.Id))) but that is messy and not easily expandable.

Comment: @user1186050 The next person that has to look at your code will thank you for using `switch`.

Comment: I've edited my OP to show the actual query. How would I add the switch to the query with the other && statements?

Comment: Changed answer to reflect updated query.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks! I didn't know you could just add/concatenate as many where statements together like that!